# Copy project connected to tfs

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I am working in VS TFS. I've a project connected to TFS which I want to copy to a local non tfs project. How do I do that? If I just copy the solution folder and rename it, it will also copy the TFS information which I don't want.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

1. In Visual Studio, select the solution in the solution explorer.
2. Go to the `File` menu.
3. Under the file menu, go to `Source Control` menu.
4. Select `Change Source Control`.
5. In the dialog box that comes up, choose `"unbind"`.